# How to interpret nested-cross validation for iris data set?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, cross-validation

I wanted to understand nested-cross validation better. I looked at the example provided in sci-kit learn, which compares non-nested and nested cross-validation strategies on a classifier of the iris data set.

I did not understand exactly what is the difference between the nested and non-nested cross-validation here and what is the advantage of using one over the other.

Does non-nested mean you didn’t optimise hyper-parameters using cross-validation, but by a simple train-validation split? Or does it mean you didn’t evaluate the test accuracies over different cross-validation splits but by a simple validation-test split? Using this approach, I have observed higher accuracies in non-nested cross-validation. Why is this the case? Shouldn’t nested cross-validation have a better basis for estimating generalization to the test set or better hyper-parameter selection? Wouldn’t better performance for non-nested simply reflect a lucky train-validation or validation-test split?

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_iris
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from sklearn.svm import SVC
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV, cross_val_score, KFold
import numpy as np

print(__doc__)

# Number of random trials
NUM_TRIALS = 30

# Load the dataset
iris = load_iris()
X_iris = iris.data
y_iris = iris.target

# Set up possible values of parameters to optimize over
p_grid = {"C": [1, 10, 100],
          "gamma": [.01, .1]}

# We will use a Support Vector Classifier with "rbf" kernel
svm = SVC(kernel="rbf")

# Arrays to store scores
non_nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)
nested_scores = np.zeros(NUM_TRIALS)

# Loop for each trial
for i in range(NUM_TRIALS):

    # Choose cross-validation techniques for the inner and outer loops,
    # independently of the dataset.
    # E.g "GroupKFold", "LeaveOneOut", "LeaveOneGroupOut", etc.
    inner_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)
    outer_cv = KFold(n_splits=4, shuffle=True, random_state=i)

    # Non_nested parameter search and scoring
    clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
    clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
    non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_

    # Nested CV with parameter optimization
    nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
    nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()

score_difference = non_nested_scores - nested_scores

print("Average difference of {:6f} with std. dev. of {:6f}."
      .format(score_difference.mean(), score_difference.std()))

# Plot scores on each trial for nested and non-nested CV
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(211)
non_nested_scores_line, = plt.plot(non_nested_scores, color='r')
nested_line, = plt.plot(nested_scores, color='b')
plt.ylabel("score", fontsize="14")
plt.legend([non_nested_scores_line, nested_line],
           ["Non-Nested CV", "Nested CV"],
           bbox_to_anchor=(0, .4, .5, 0))
plt.title("Non-Nested and Nested Cross Validation on Iris Dataset",
          x=.5, y=1.1, fontsize="15")

# Plot bar chart of the difference.
plt.subplot(212)
difference_plot = plt.bar(range(NUM_TRIALS), score_difference)
plt.xlabel("Individual Trial #")
plt.legend([difference_plot],
           ["Non-Nested CV - Nested CV Score"],
           bbox_to_anchor=(0, 1, .8, 0))
plt.ylabel("score difference", fontsize="14")

plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1):

Just like you I was confused, at first, by this example, but everything got clear after I looked at [this thread](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/issues/9470). To sum it up, at each iteration of the loop two scores are computed:

1. The non-nested score:

```
clf = GridSearchCV(estimator=svm, param_grid=p_grid, cv=inner_cv)
clf.fit(X_iris, y_iris)
non_nested_scores[i] = clf.best_score_
```

This is the score of the best model tuned by performing a 4-fold cross validation on the whole dataset.

2. The nested score:

```
nested_score = cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
nested_scores[i] = nested_score.mean()
```

Here comes the key point I didn't get at first: `cross_val_score` computes the 4-fold cross validation score of `clf` which is a `GridSearchCV` object, not the best estimator found before. This means that the code

```
cross_val_score(clf, X=X_iris, y=y_iris, cv=outer_cv)
```

divides the whole dataset into 4 folds (so you have 4 different train/test splits). Then at each split it calls `clf.fit()` on the train set, which performs another independent grid search. Lastly, it calls `clf.score()` on the test set, which computes the score on the test set of the best estimator found in the grid search.

Note that the purpose of nested cross validation is to find an unbiased estimate of the generalization error of your model. The non-nested scores are higher because they are computed on subsets of the data which were used in training and so they are too optimistic. On the other end, the nested scores were computed on separate test sets which were not used for model selection, hence they provide a more realistic estimate of the accuracy of your model when you apply it on unseen data.